# Video camera to upload footage to Azure

Tags: azure, video, camera, backup, surveillance

We have an UVC camera from Ubiquiti and I'd like to upload the surveillance footage to Azure cloud, I don't want to do a daily backup of the footage, I need the footage to be uploaded directly to Azure somehow. Can I do this?

Comment: This is a question for the camera vendor, but I'm guessing you'll have to create your own footage-upload mechanism. In any case: Not a question that can be answered here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Not an Azure user myself, but I guess you could try mounting your Azure file share using webdav (on windows you can try this [guide](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/mounting-your-azure-file-shares-on-premises-through-webdav/), on linux you can mount using davfs2, there are plenty of guides out there). After that, change the NVR recording path to your webdav share and you should be all set.

Take into account, thought, that this will be really sub-optimal, for at least 2 reasons:

1) In case your internet connection goes down, you'll be losing recording footage.
2) Writing real-time data to a remote share (especially mounted using webdav) is never a good idea. Carefully take into account latency and throughput. Preferably do some tests first.

A better option would be to record locally and schedule a task (or cron job, if you're on linux) to move the files offsite every night/month/whatever, and only after successful completion remove it off the local disk.